# Google Maps showing wrong current location

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I am using google maps in my sencha touch application. And I am using current location as true. But some time I am getting my current location different some time.

Below is the code I have used to show map.

```
   this.map = new Ext.Map({
    mapOptions : {
        zoom: 12,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
        }
    },
    useCurrentLocation: true,
});
```

Comment: How different does it show ? Minor differences will exist, it's won't show 100% accurate location.

Comment: on what this map api depends ie on GPS or on the service provider??